# Can Epson Stylus Photo 800FW print in black if any ink cartridge is empty?

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer, epson-stylus

I want to buy [Epson Stylus Photo 800FW](https://www.epson.co.uk/products/printers/inkjet-printers/consumer/epson-stylus-photo-px800fw) .

Can it print paper in black n white even if any of the ink cartridge is dry or empty?

Sorry, I have absolutely no idea about printers and the things to take care of before buying. I don't need to take printouts quite often (4-5 prints in a month) and I just need a backup option at home. Please also let me know if this printer will be a suitable printer as my requirement.

Comment: In regards to printing in black - you are better off asking Epson directly (unless by some chance someone has that exact printer and can offer their experience on it). Also whether it will be suitable for your requirement or not is 100% opinion based and will not be suitable for this site.

Comment: Most printers will simply refuse to print if any one cartridge reads as empty. For low volume printing, I would always recommend laser over inject. It never dries out & will still be good in 10 years' time, by which time you just recycle it & buy a new printer. With an inkjet over 10 years you will spend far more more on replacing ink than you would buying a laser & using it til it runs out. I just checked the web page - ink is £75, that's half the price of an entire laser printer.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I contacted Epson and asked about it. They said that I cannot use the printer if any of the ink is dried or empty.